# Connected functions and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to prove or find a counter-example of this:

> If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a connected, then $f$ is continuous.
>
> (A function $f$ is connected if and only if the image under $f$ of any connected set is a connected set.)

I was trying to find a counter-examples because I think it is not true, but now I'm not sure.

I can use the fact that the connected sets in $\mathbb{R} $ are the intervals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Converse_is_false

Answer (score 3):

One easy to write down example is

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
          0 \quad x= 0 \\
          \sin \frac{1}{x} \quad x\neq0 \
       \end{cases}$